# Как авторизоваться на сайте через vbs?

Tags: vbscript

Недавно познакомился со встроенным в винду языком VBS. Мне в голову пришла идея сделать через него авторизацию в одноклассниках чтобы вручную не вводить

Сделал это :

```
Set a = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
a.run "firefox.exe"
WScript.sleep 1000
a.run "http:ok.ru"
Wscript.sleep 5000
(здесь собственно и вопрос)
a.SendKeys "Логин"
a.SendKeys "{Tab}"
a.SendKeys "Пароль"
a.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

Вопрос: Как перевести курсор в поле ввода логина? Пробовал TABом - не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Моя реализация вашей задачи.

```
Option Explicit

'Запускаем браузер
Dim oIE : Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    oIE.Visible = True
    oIE.Navigate "http://ok.ru"

'Ждём когда загрузится сайт
WScript.Sleep 1000

'Получаем доступ к форме
Dim email_field : Set email_field = oIE.document.getElementById("field_email")
Dim password_field : Set password_field = oIE.document.getElementById("field_password")
Dim form_submit : Set form_submit=oIE.document.forms(0)

email_field.value="" 'ваш логин
password_field.value="" 'ваш пароль
form_submit.Submit 'отправляем данные
```